# Excel VBA Save sheet so it opens on last row

Tags: vba, excel

This should be dead simple but i'm throwing a total blank so far, i've googled around and not found an answer either.

I'm creating a new workbook using VBA and i'd like to save that workbook so that it opens on the last row containing data when the user opens it. This is what i have so far:-

```
   With ActiveWorkbook
        'Added a last row selection so the sheet will open at the bottom of the page - Ash 07/04/14
        LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Activate
        .SaveAs str_DestFolder & str_File, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlShared
        .Close
    End With
```

Somehow this is failing me, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following line, after activating your last row:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

So your full code would be

```
    With ActiveWorkbook
        LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
        .SaveAs str_DestFolder & str_File, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlShared
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I was starting to look into copying a module across to the new workbook etc but this is so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions

- Code that should be run to set the workbook up for the next open should be run in the `BeforeSave` or `Open` Events.
- best to run the code to work on a specific sheet automatically (the first sheet in the sample below) rather than rely on it being active.
- Excell 2007 and onwards have 1 million rows, so either use `Cells(Row.Count,"A").End(xlup)` or `Find` rather than Range("A65536").End(xlup)`.

code for the *ThisWorkbook* module (runs automatically on save)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A:A").Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
Application.Goto rng1
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = rng1.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @brettdj . What my actual full code is doing is extracting data from one workbook, creating a new workbook then copying across all the data into the first sheet. This is all on an automated job that runs every 10 minutes and starts a new workbook at midnight every day. I really wanted to avoid trying to add code into these newly created workbooks if i could avoid it, luckily Davids answer works pefectly for me in this case - the users only want to see the last hour or so of data whenver they look at the new workbook. The Cells(Row.Count,"A").End(xlup) is a great point btw!

Comment: @LuckySevens no probs, glad to hear you have it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
LastRow = Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, 1).Select
With Wb
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs Filename:="YourFilePath",  AccessMode:=xlShared
    .Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End With
Set Wb = Nothing
```

Try this...

Comment: Thanks for this, im sure it works just fine, Davids answer is just a simpler solution.